# Creating sequence for longer numeric values

Tags: postgresql, auto-increment, postgresql-8.4

I need to create a `database model` that includes a field to store 20 digit unique values. Which will be used by many clients over an API.

The value **must** be 20 digit long, numeric and unique. Best approach seemed to create an auto increment `big-int` field, but big-int supports values up to 9223372036854775807 (19 digits). Using `numeric(20,0)` is useless since although numeric supports larger values, Postgres 8.4 do not let me create a `sequence` and raises error

```
CREATE SEQUENCE my_sequence_name INCREMENT BY 1 NO MINVALUE NO MAXVALUE START WITH 10000000000000000101;
```

> ERROR:  value "10000000000000000101" is out of range for type bigint

For data integrity, I must handle this within POstgresql. What is the efficient way to handle this?

I am using Postgresql 8.4 and Django 1.3

***UPDATE:*** I guess it is better to make a clarification...
I am trying to find a way to solve this within DBMS. So any non-database solutions will be avoided unless I had no other choice. Rest is the reason of my question:

I am making an API which communicates with a Bank for 3D secure operations. The bank API required a **20 digit unique numeric identifier** for the transaction, so I decided to create an ID value that I can both use for the bank API and *my API* that will use that table etc.

Stating from `10000000000000000101` is because, bank API want it to be a **valid** 20 digit `integer` value, so It must be at least 10000000000000000000.

Solving this within the DBMS is best for performance and data integrity. An idea I thought  was storing the value as an `auto-increment big-integer` in the database field, and manually parse it to string and make some make-up like:

```
bid = str(23434545) # value in the DB field
final_value = '1' + '0'* (19-len(bid)) + bid
```

which make `final_value` a 20 digit integer that starts with 1 and end with my auto-incremented value. and middle is filled with zeros.

But in case of dealing with both `SELECT` and `INSERT` queries, Keeping the logic out of the DBMS is bas, so so bad.

Comment: Are you sure the values don't need to be unpredictable (random, or at least pseudo-random)?

Comment: @CraigRinger yes, I am sure, in fact, they told me it is better to be a sequence value.

Comment: Is it ok to have gaps in the sequence?

Comment: @MikeSherrill'Catcall' preffered is no, but it is ok if there occurs some.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you can live with losing some values to the maximum value, you could combine a sequence with a fixed offset to get the 20 digits. I would also define a check constraint on the table to to make sure that accidental inserts without using the default value insert the wrong value:

```
create sequence my_sequence_name;
create table foo 
(
   id numeric(20,0) default 10000000000000000001 + nextval('my_sequence_name'),
   constraint check_range check (id between 10000000000000000001 and 99999999999999999999)
);
```

That will give you a maximum generated value of 19223372036854775808 which doesn't use the complete range of allowed values, but it might be enough for your needs.

Comment: or `check (id between 10000000000000000001 and 19223372036854775808)`?

Comment: @JackDouglas: would make sense as well, yes. `99999999999999999999` "complies" with the actual business requirement, that's why I used that.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution would be to do the append on the server side like this:

```
INSERT INTO record(bid, ...) VALUES('1' || lpad(nextval('bid'), 19, '0'))
```

Comment: What will be the type of `bid` in here?

Comment: @FallenAngel `text`. Which is quite reasonable if the API specifies "20 digits" rather than "a value between ... and ..." like a sensibly written one would.